# New a one-dimensional array which is extremely big like 60000*60000

Tags: c++, arrays

Language: C++
System: Windows 7 x64
Memory: 8GB RAM

I wanna new a large one-dimensional array in my 64-bit application, which contains 60000*60000=3600000000 unsigned short type elements.
Purpose to read a very big picture which is 60k*60k pixels and turn that into one-demensional array to take further process. I certainly could split that picture and read them separately , but in production environment, i do have 128GB and more RAM to consume.

#### 1. static method

`unsigned short array [3600000000];`
it shows ***error: size of array 'a' is negative***

#### 2.malloc approach:

```
unsigned long long bytes = 3600000000 * sizeof(unsigned short);  
unsigned short *arr;  
arr = (unsigned short *)malloc(bytes);//almost 6.7GB memory
```

In my pc with 8GB RAM, address of arr is 0x0 when debug at line malloc
in other pc with 16GB RAM, the address of arr is valid, but if i assign value to each item in arr like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned short *arr;
    arr = (unsigned short *)malloc(3600000000 * sizeof(unsigned short));//memory space can be allocate to arr, about 6.7GB
    if (arr == NULL){
        cout << "failed"<< endl;
    }
    memset(arr, 1, sizeof(arr));
    cout << arr << endl;
}
```

Interruption will occured at some weird memory location arr is 0x11103630A52B112.
in my pc x64 with 8GB RAM, it print "failed"
in other pc x64 with 16GB RAM, the address of arr is valid, but if i assign value to each item in arr with for loop, interruption will occured at some wired memory location arr is 0x11103630A52B112
how could i new a very very big one-dimentional array

1.(static method 8GB) it shows ***error: size of array 'a' is negative***
2.(malloc approach 8GB)[error log with my 8GB and memset statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M795.png)

```
oneDimensionalArray.cpp: In function 'int main()':
oneDimensionalArray.cpp:10:47: warning: unsigned conversion from 'long long int' to 'size_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} changes value from '7200000000' to '2905032704' [-Woverflow]
     arr = (unsigned short *)malloc(3600000000 * sizeof(unsigned short));//memory space can be allocate to arr, about 6.7GB
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
oneDimensionalArray.cpp:10:35: warning: argument 1 value '2905032704' exceeds maximum object size 2147483647 [-Walloc-size-larger-than=]
     arr = (unsigned short *)malloc(3600000000 * sizeof(unsigned short));//memory space can be allocate to arr, about 6.7GB
                             ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from folderPath\mingw\installed\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\cstdlib:75,
                 from folderPath\mingw\installed\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\ext\string_conversions.h:41,
                 from folderPath\mingw\installed\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:6391,
                 from folderPath\mingw\installed\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\string:52,
                 from folderPath\mingw\installed\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from folderPath\mingw\installed\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from folderPath\mingw\installed\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from folderPath\mingw\installed\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from folderPath\mingw\installed\lib\gcc\mingw32\8.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from oneDimensionalArray.cpp:1:
folderPath\mingw\installed\include\stdlib.h:503:40: note: in a call to allocation function 'void* malloc(size_t)' declared here
 _CRTIMP __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  void *malloc (size_t) __MINGW_ATTRIB_MALLOC;
                                        ^~~~~~
failed
```

3.(malloc approach 16GB) ***An exception was raised: write access rights conflict, arr is 0x11103630A52B112*** at assign statament *arr[i] = 1;* in for loop

Comment: Memory mapping?

Comment: What's your question? The array has not big size, it has negative size, since 3600000000 > MAX_INT and therefore overflows.

Comment: `for(long long i=0;i<byte,i++){` this line looks wrong

Comment: `C or C++, Windows 7 x64, 8GB RAM` -- This does not say if your application is 32-bit or 64-bit.  This only describes the operating system, not the application running.  So is your application 32-bit or 64-bit?  If it's 32-bit, all of that RAM you're talking about is going to waste.

Comment: Also, please choose a language C or C++ (you are including `<iostream>`, and that does not exist for `C`).  For C++, and assuming your program is 64-bit, `std::vector<unsigned short> arr(3600000000, 1);` will either throw an exception, or just work (but maybe slow on the allocation).  No need for all of this checking you're doing now, and no need to write the loop setting all the elements to 1.

Comment: " at some wired memory location" is likely " at some weird memory location"

Comment: @dyukha: 3600000000 does not have type `int`. It has type `long` or `long long` depending on whether it fits in `long` on this C implementation, which looks like it's a buggy one (probably MSVC).

Comment: @R.., is it starting from C++11? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal I definitely remember how writing such literals overflows even when the variable has big enough type. But it was before C++11.

Comment: @dyukha: This goes at least all the way back to C99 and I think even to C89, but there was no `long long` in C89 so a large literal was still a problem then. Not sure about corresponding C++ versions.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How to determine my application is 32-bit or 64-bit, it supposed to be an 64-bit applocation.  
C++ preferd, and is your ```std::vector``` worked?
From my perspective, i need to make my container full of pixels data later, so i need some way to operate each element in this array.

Comment: @Bueryoung Going by the post and the pointer value, it seems to be 64-bit app.  But this is something (determining the bit-ness of your application) you **must** be able to determine.  Otherwise you're developing an application and not knowing the architecture, and that would be considered unacceptable in a professional (even a non-professional) environment.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  ok, 64-bit application.
Could we move back to make my 3600000000 array work?

Comment: [See this](http://www.ideone.com/u7E9R9).  There is no issue with using a `vector` of that size.  Why not do that, instead of resorting to `C` and `malloc`?  All of these issues you had that have been pointed out by the answers given are solved by using C++ (std::vector).  No compiler errors, no need for loops to initialize the elements, etc.  As I stated before, either `std::vector` will throw an exception, or it will just work correctly.  Your list of "methods" in your post totally missed the obvious one -- `std::vector`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What is this website stand for, i could not open it or link to the other websit full of game advertisements.    
Could you please provide contents here? Thx.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i tried `std::vector` in my VSCode, but it still appear some error.        
 
```vector<long long> nVec;  
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 3600000000; ++i){  
        nVec.push_back(i);  
    }  
```  
error log:  
`workspace\oneDimensionalArray terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'  
  what():  std::bad_alloc  
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.`  
Does it due to 36000000 beyound size_t?

Comment: @Bueryoung This is why you should be aware of the bitness of your application.  I took the code from the link and made sure the compilation was for 64-bit within Visual Studio.  There were no issues (the debug mode to a while, but release was ok).  You were probably building a 32-bit program, not 64 bit.

Comment: Also, there is no need for the loop and push_back.  Just a single declaration:  `std::vector<unsigned short> arr(360000000,1);`  Second, what is `arr.max_size();`?

Answer (score 9):

You have the line:

```
unsigned long long bytes = 3600000000 * sizeof(unsigned short);
```

This looks correct for the **amount of memory** to allocate but you also use the same value to iterate over the array:

```
for(long long i = 0; i<bytes;i++){
    arr[i] = 1;
}
```

This is wrong, there are only `3600000000` elements in the array, not `3600000000 * sizeof(unsigned short)`. You are writing past the end of the allocated memory.

Comment: N.B: This would not have happened with a std::vector<unsigned short>

Comment: @Blastfurnace How about my memset statement to assignment value to this array.  
Is that possible to make that length of 3600000000 array work?

Comment: @Bueryoung 1) It's not a good idea to change the question. Removing the original code kind of invalidates this answer. 2) No, `memset(arr, 1, sizeof(arr));` is not the solution. The `memset()` function writes `byte` values to memory and `unsigned short` is most likely two-bytes each. In addition `sizeof(arr)` is the size of the **pointer** variable, not the number of elements allocated or size of the allocated memory block.

Comment: @Blastfurnace yes, u r right, sizeof(arr) euquals 4 and i need to make enough space to contain elements.   
e.g. ten unsigned short number, need 10*sizeof(unsigned short) memory,is this right?   
`unsigned short *arr;  arr = (unsigned short *)malloc(10 * sizeof(unsigned short));  
    if (arr == NULL){  
        cout << "failed"<< endl;  
    }  
    cout << "sizeof(arr): " << sizeof(arr) << endl;   
    memset(arr, 0, sizeof(unsigned short)*1);  cout <<"arr[0]: " <<*arr << endl;  
`
sorry for the format of code, could not have a new line with two space surrounded by ' '

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Blastfurnace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56783363/2410359) good observation about using too large an index:

Potential overflow in "other pc with 16GB RAM, the address of `arr` is valid"

If `size_t` is 32-bit, `malloc(bytes)` converts `bytes`, which is more than `SIZE_MAX` to a much smaller value than `3600000000 * sizeof(unsigned short)`.  A valid pointer is return, but not for the desired size.

Instead of `unsigned long long bytes`, use `size_t bytes`, enable all warnings and guard that the math `3600000000 * sizeof(unsigned short)` does not overflow.

```
#if 3600000000 > SIZE_MAX/sizeof(unsigned short)
#error overflow
#endif
size_t bytes = 3600000000 * sizeof(unsigned short);
```

---

> read a very big picture which is 60k*60k pixels

To solve OP's higher problem, do **not** allocate `3600000000 * sizeof(unsigned short)` bytes for a 60k*60k `unsigned short` array.

Instead allocate 60k times for 60k `unsigned short` arrays.

(OP is using C++, but appears to want to use `malloc()`.  `new` would be more C++ like.)

```
size_t rows = 60000;
size_t cols = 60000;
unsigned short = initial_value;
unsigned short **pix = (unsigned short **) mallow(sizeof *pix * rows);
assert(pix);

for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
  pix[r] = (unsigned short *) mallow(sizeof *pix[r] * cols);
  assert(pix[r]);
  for (size_t c = 0; c < rows; c++) {
    pix[r][c] = initial_value;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, i got 2905032704 from my program in that index of arr.

Comment: @Bueryoung The index of `arr` found is not the salient issue.  Size of `size_t` (32 or 64 bit) and use `for(size_t i = 0; i<3600000000;i++){
        arr[i] = 1;
    }`

Comment: i change the way to ```memset```, but it still not work. It seems not due to index, how to fix that?

Comment: @chux -- Honestly, your method is not a good one to allocate for a 2D matrix.  You're allocating each row separately, [when you could/should do something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You  referenced code has `nrows*ncols` and it is that product that 1 ) may overflow or 2) may be too large for a single `new` of `short`.  These problems are implied in OP's post.   Allocating individual rows is _good_ to prevent hitting  that limit.  Yes for small 2D arrays, a single allocation is faster